# ApiController with ActionNameAttribute is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created this controller which is working:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class LLWebReportViewerController : ControllerBase {
    [HttpGet("FrontendVersionWRV")]
    public bool FrontendVersionWRV(string frontendVersion) {
        // ... do something

        return true;
    }
}
```

When I try to use the ActionNameAttribute and execute the HTTPGet-Call, the Method will not be found anymore:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class LLWebReportViewerController : ControllerBase {
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("FrontendVersionWRV")]
    public bool FrontendVersionWRV(string frontendVersion) {
        // ... do something

        return true;
    }
}
```

The Problem is, that I cannot change it to only using the HttpGetAttribute because it is a Third-Party Library.

Can someone give me a hint what I have to do, that my API will find the Endpoint with the ActionNameAttribute?

Comment: What is the .net version? is it an mvc project or asp.net core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `[Route("api/[controller]")]` to `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]`  to make the `[ActionName]` work.